# Run Tizen emulator (preview Visual Studio plugin) in VMware Fusion

Tags: visual-studio, qemu, tizen, vmware-fusion, tizen-emulator

I'm trying to setup an environment to develop Tizen app with the Visual Studio Tools. Thus I installed Windows 8 on Fusion VM (OS X El Capitan) with VT-x enabled. On the Windows 8 host, I've installed necessary requirements including Tizen Intel HAXM and Tizen Visual Studio Tools; the build process was finished without any errors. However, I could not launch Tizen emulator as it always shows error dialog in the screenshot.

"-device vigs,backend=gl,wsi=vigs_wsi: Device initialization failed"

Does anybody know how to tackle this issue? Or any other solution to develop Tizen projects with Visual Studio on my Mac?

[image: Launch Tizen Emulator]

Comment: Possibly related to [nested VM functionality](https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8970), can you run Windows Phone/Visual Studio Android emulator there? Also try the answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883606/windows-phone-8-emulator-in-vmware-fusion-on-osx)

Comment: look about qemu inside vmware support or try other emulation systems like :

Answer (score 0):

look about qemu inside vmware support

or try other emulation systems based on wine :

https://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/crossover/visual-studio-tools-for-tizen